# Definir limite del arega para un objeto dragable en 'swingdrag'

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Tengo este ejemplo de  jQuery UI plugin - swingdrag.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Customizable-Swing-Effect-On-Drag-Drop-swingdrag/

Ese plugin tiene varias funciones, pero no tiene la funcion para establecer limites del objeto que se arrastra.

Por ejemplo:
- Tengo un div Principal (500x500px) y adentro tengo el objeto arrastrable (200x200px). Como establecer el limite de area(500x500) para ese objeto?
- O por ejeplo establecer el limite del area que ocupe toda la resolucion del monitor, para que no se pase como en el link que deje.

PD: Por que me quiero usar jQuery swingdrag Plugin y no la libreria draggable? Porque el primero tiene lindos efectos de (sombra, angulo de rotacion, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione.

Fucione el plugin - swingdrag con Draggable Widget.

Por un lado viene el codigo de swingdrag que da mejor visualizacion a mi objeto draggable y por otro lado query de Draggable Widget que calcula limites del area y otras fisicas.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="dist/jquery.ui.swingdrag.min.js"></script>
      
      <style>
         .draggable-4 { 
            width: 90px; height: 50px; padding: 0.5em; float: left;
            margin: 0px 5px 10px 0;
            border: 1px solid red;  
            background-color:#B9CD6D;
         }
         .droppable-7 { 
            width: 100px; height: 90px;padding: 0.5em; float: left; 
            margin: 10px; 
            border: 1px solid black; 
            background-color:#A39480;
         }
         .droppable.active { 
            background-color: red; 
         }
   
      </style>
      
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $('.draggable-4').draggable({ 
   containment: "window",
   revert: true });
            $('.droppable-7').droppable({
               hoverClass: 'active',
               drop: function(e, ui) {
                  $(this).html(ui.draggable.remove().html());
                  $(this).droppable('destroy');
                  $( this )
                  .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                  .find( "p" )
                  .html( "i'm destroyed!" );
               }
            });
         });
   
      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <div class = "draggable-4"><p>drag 1</p></div>
      <div class = "draggable-4"><p>drag 2</p></div>
      <div class = "draggable-4"><p>drag 3</p></div>

      <div style = "clear: both;padding:10px"></div>

      <div class = "droppable-7">drop here</div>
      <div class = "droppable-7">drop here</div>
      <div class = "droppable-7">drop here</div>
   </body>
   
    <script>
  $(".draggable-4").swingdrag({
   rotationAngleDeg: 8,
   showShadow: true,
   pickUpScaleFactor: 1.1
  });
  
 </script>
</html>
```